# Is there a way to get DFP revenue/cpm by URL?

Tags: google-adsense, google-dfp, doubleclick-ad-exchange

Can we get the revenue generated by (the ads on) each of the individual URLs on my website? Other than, you know, by adding URL channels manually at both Adsense and Ad Exchange and then summing up the revenues.

I know that the [`SlotRenderEndedEvent`](https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-gpt/reference?hl=en#googletageventsslotrenderendedevent) of the GPT API can give me information as far as the line item id, service that rendered the ad slot etc. Can it, may be, give more info like the pricing rule used (at adx) etc - so that I can get an estimate on the revenue?

Any other new solution is also fine - as long as it's not adding URL channels manually. (There is no API to add URL channels to Adx).

PS: I do not have Google Analytics Premium, so I cannot connect DFP to GA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you won't get any pricing data from the event.  But you can get the line item and potentially other useful info from the event.  You can query the DFP reporting (even without premium) to get the impressions/revenue for that line item.

If you have other key-value data you pass through, you can get more detailed info about revenue broken apart by the different KV.